# XSLT - copy only specific elements with its children (so not the parent of the node)

Tags: xml, xslt

How do I copy only specific elements with their children? So, not the parent elements.

Example XLST file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <header>Some inserted text</header>
    <xsl:template match="staff">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="subelement"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="subelement">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</parent>
```

Example XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<company>
    <staff attrib="select" id="1001">
        <name>should-1</name>
        <role>copy-1</role>
    </staff>
    <staff id="1002">
        <name>should-3</name>
        <role>not-copy-3</role>
    </staff>
    <staff attrib="select" id="1002">
        <name>should-2</name>
        <role>copy-2</role>
    </staff>
</company>
```

Wanted result: ( so, no 'company' element )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <parent><header>Some inserted text</header>
      <staff attrib="select" id="1001">
        <name>should-1</name>
        <role>copy-1</role>
      </staff>
      <staff id="1002">
        <name>should-3</name>
        <role>not-copy-3</role>
      </staff>
      <staff attrib="select" id="1002">
        <name>should-2</name>
        <role>copy-2</role>
      </staff>
  </parent>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <parent><p>Some inserted text</p>
    <company>
      <staff attrib="select" id="1001">
        <name>should-1</name>
        <role>copy-1</role>
      </staff>
      <staff id="1002">
        <name>should-3</name>
        <role>not-copy-3</role>
      </staff>
      <staff attrib="select" id="1002">
        <name>should-2</name>
        <role>copy-2</role>
      </staff>
    </company>
  </parent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/company">
    <parent>
        <header>Some inserted text</header>
        <xsl:copy-of select="staff"/>
    </parent>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```