# XSLT - select only elements with a specific attribute value (but get all)

Tags: xml, xslt

When I select elements with a specific attribute value, still all elements are selected. Why?
So, I applied a standard solution but it does not work. Tried many alternatieves without success. Yup, XLST is pretty new for me.

XLST:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/company/staff[@attrib = 'select']">
        <parent>
            <header>Some inserted text</header>
            <xsl:copy-of select="staff"/>
        </parent>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<company>
    <staff attrib="select" id="1001">
        <name>should-1</name>
        <role>copy-1</role>
    </staff>
    <staff id="1002">
        <name>should-3</name>
        <role>not-copy-3</role>
    </staff>
    <staff attrib="select" id="1003">
        <name>should-2</name>
        <role>copy-2</role>
    </staff>
</company>
```

In the result I see 'staff' element with id="1002" even when it does not have the specific attribute value.

Wanted result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><parent><header>Some inserted text</header><company>
    <staff attrib="select" id="1001">
        <name>should-1</name>
        <role>copy-1</role>
    </staff>
    <staff attrib="select" id="1003">
        <name>should-2</name>
        <role>copy-2</role>
    </staff>
</company></parent>
```

Actual result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><parent><header>Some inserted text</header><company>
    <staff attrib="select" id="1001">
        <name>should-1</name>
        <role>copy-1</role>
    </staff>
    <staff id="1002">
        <name>should-3</name>
        <role>not-copy-3</role>
    </staff>
    <staff attrib="select" id="1003">
        <name>should-2</name>
        <role>copy-2</role>
    </staff>
</company></parent>
```

Comment: What you posted is not an XSLT file. Also, a template matching `/staff[@attrib = 'select']` will never match anything unless `staff` is the root element. And you have a template matching `subelement` - but there is no such node in your XML. Altogether a fine mess.

Comment: It looks like an attempt to use the "simplified syntax" a.k.a. [Literal Result Element as Stylesheet](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#result-element-stylesheet). But such stylesheet cannot contain templates or any other top-level elements. --- I suggest you use the standard syntax, as shown in your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72976257/3016153

Comment: Sorry, totally agree. Took the XLST from an example tutorial. I renewed the XLST.

Comment: Find a better tutorial!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/company">
    <parent>
        <header>Some inserted text</header>
        <xsl:copy-of select="staff[@attrib = 'select']"/>
    </parent>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```